# Why are the reasons behind the common pronunciation-spelling mismatches in English?

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling

For example, why aren't "t"s pronounced like "d"s spelled as "d"s? Why isn't spot spelled sbot? What about "ph"s and "gh"s?
I'd like to form a comprehensive list--so there should be one answer that gets edited.

Comment: For one, *utter* and *udder* are different words—and they are also pronounced differently …

Comment: So, would you promote different spellings for different accents?  How about spelling that changes over time to follow the latest pronunciation?

Comment: Accent-related spelling has been tried, and it solves nothing. Related is [Eye dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_dialect).

Comment: This question **might** be useful for an answer mentioning the Great Vowel Shift, I suppose. But I'm not convinced your examples are not good ones.

Comment: "*For example, why aren't "t"s pronounced like "d"s spelled as "d"s?*" Have you any examples?

Comment: @Greybeard such as *Jan is a bedder bedder*?

Comment: Ha! Is the question about the "t=flap"?

Comment: Many spellings are based on how words were pronounced hundreds of years ago.

Comment: Well, there's "siddown".

Comment: I think it would be more productive to have a separate question for each mismatch. One question asking about "t"s versus "d"s, one question about "sbot", one about "ph", one about "gh", and so on.

Comment: @Tanner Swett, that doesn't make for a good reference, since the reason you'd ask about one of those is the same reason you would ask for any of them. I have tried to find the answer to this question and finding various articles for each of them is unproductive.        <br/> An example of precedent for this kind of question would be the comprehensive list of confusing acronyms.